# No data retrieved from instagram

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, instagram

Since Instagram API is not working, I am trying to crawl information of a given hashtag. On the search page of Hash-Tag, it has Ajax embedded, so I followed rules online to look for url where the data is retrieved. Then I have the following link.

https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=f92f56d47dc7a55b606908374b43a314&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22%3A%22cancun%22%2C%22show_ranked%22%3Afalse%2C%22first%22%3A20%2C%22after%22%3A%22QVFENlVELW9hZjlJVWU1RWd6anpWdGNsYkVwU3M5TzUtaDlRN3VoRHlwU1EwWWRBZ2t6TFkzbEl1M3RRcmItd0JKbVBiM2pLUXZpT0JzNWp3dFhIcElfWg%3D%3D%22%7D

However, When I am trying crawl that page using Urlopen, Instagram blocked my crawler. I tried to use User-Agent to get around it, and it is not working.
Then I tried to use Webdriver to fake the browser, it gets around the blockage, but I don't get anything from the crawling. 
Does anyone know what is wrong with that.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless') 
driver.get(url)
pagesource = driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pagesource,'html.parser')
print(bsObj.prettify())
```

Appreciate any Help!

Comment: You may want to look into [`WebdriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to make sure the driver is giving the page enough time to load.

Comment: just wait until some element load finish. But you may try several time on different locate function